# Android CWAC Camera - Return true from mirrorFFC does not work for Samsung device(S4)

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac, cwac-camera

I am using the CWAC camera within my app. The mirrorFFC set to true in my custom camera host class, is working fine with my Xiaomi Redmi2 i.e it correctly mirrors the image. However when I sent a build to a friend who **has the Samsung S4, the image is not mirrored**. Do I need to make any specific change for Samsung devices or for specific devices?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the image is too big for the available heap space, and we ran out of memory attempting to mirror the image. The documentation contains [some advice for this scenario](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/README-original.markdown#fixing-up-images-and-your-heap).

Also note that this library is no longer being actively developed, due to the issues outlined in [the project `README`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera).

Comment: Hi Mark. Is there a way to trigger what happens in onPause and OnResume without actually leaving the activity like you do in the Demo App. By that I mean calling pause and resume on the  cameraView object.  I am using the Eventbus library - maybe some sort of event to trigger something??

Comment: @Rohan: Well, if you host the `CameraView` object yourself, in theory you can do whatever you want.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't really understand the "host the Cameraview object" bit.

Comment: @Rohan: `CameraView` is a `View`. You can put it in your layout yourself, as is described in [the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/README-original.markdown#working-directly-with-cameraview).

Comment: I'm adding the camera view programatically actually in OnCreateView of my fragment. The CameraView instance is got by calling the super class.

Comment: I have figured a work around, by calling onPause on the CameraView and onResume again but this causes addition and removal of views .The members of Cameraview are private and I cannot enable/disable onOrientationChange as well as set the lastPictureOrientation.

Comment: The issue I'm facing actually is the orientation getting messed up if I stay in the same activity to display the captured pic and while taking successive pictures. In the demo app,you have handled it by starting a new activity which triggers an onPause for the fragment and subsequently calls onPause on the CameraView.

Comment: I would like to trigger the onPause and onResume on the camera view without the actual removal of the view. Is that possible?
If I stay in the same activity and try to take more than one pic, the following image preview gets rotated since the onPause did not get called on the camera view object. I've been stuck on this issue for a while. Could you please give me some advice on how to move forward?

Comment: @Rohan: Get rid of my library and work with the camera APIs directly.

Comment: Working with my own code, right now. Trying to the phase the cwac lib out. Just need to make sure I  handle memory issues well.